# Capturing the click on "like" button on a Page Tabs

Tags: facebook, events, button, tabs

I'm trying to know when an user clicks on the "like" button.

Everything I can find leads me to the "FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', ...)" thing, but it doesn't seem to work on **page tabs**...

Does anyone know a way to capture this event on tabs ?

Thanks a lot for your help.